# Change parameters value in a method during its execution in a thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I would like to know if there is a way to dynamically change the parameters passed to a method when it running in a thread.

For example:

```
trdColCycl thread = new Thread (() => this.ColorsCycling (true));
trdColCycl.Start();
```

or

```
trdColCycl thread = new Thread (new ParameterizedThreadStart (this.ColorsCycling));
trdColCycl.Start(true);
```

and then I want to pass as a parameter to the thread running the value `false` ... is it possible?
(in this example I would like to dynamically change the parameter value to exit from a loop inside the thread without using global variables)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a shared variable meant for communicating between two threads

```
class ArgumentObject
{
    public bool isOk;
}

// later
thread1Argument = new ArgumentObject() { isOk = true };
TrdColCycl thread = new Thread (() => this.ColorsCycling (thread1Argument));
trdColCycl.Start();

// much later
thread1Argument.isOk = false;
```

## Edit:

Alternatively, you could pass the bool as reference instead:

```
bool isOk = true;
TrdColCycl thread = new Thread (() => this.ColorsCycling (ref isOk));
trdColCycl.Start();

// later
isOk = false;
```

In both cases, you'll have to modify the signature of your method:

```
// original
void ColorsCycling(bool isOk)
// should be
void ColorsCycling(ArgumentObject argument) // for option 1
// or
void ColorsCycling(ref bool isOk) // for option 2
```